# Tensorflow - What is the difference between shapes (8,1) and (8,)

Tags: tensorflow

What is the difference between shapes `(8,1)` and `(8,)`?
They both seem to define a vector of length 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TensorFlow, these are different shapes. The shape `(8,)` represents a vector of length 8, whereas the shape `(8, 1)` represents a matrix with 8 rows and 1 column.

While these objects can often be treated as the same mathematically, they have an important distinction in frameworks like TensorFlow (and NumPy), because they determine how operators are [broadcasted](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). For example, multiplying a tensor of shape `(8, 1)` and a tensor of shape `(8,)` will give a result of shape `(8, 8)`. This feature can be used to save time and memory by implicitly tiling a tensor (or array) along one or more dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

`[[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1]]`
and
`[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]`

[image: tensorflow shape]

In my understanding , the sub/right dim is to split the left dim